# Which altitude profile and height is optimal for Everesting by hiking?

Tags: hiking, trail-running

[Everesting](https://everesting.cc/) is an activity where the goal is altitude gain of 8848 m or more by repeatedly going up and down a selected route.

This is most often attempted by biking; however, hiking/running is practiced too. The whole process takes 20-30 hours; however, the time seems to be less important than the feat itself.

I would like to understand how to choose a route which makes this possible.

The rules (described on the [site](https://everesting.cc/run-rules/), but I added a few of my own) are:

- Total elevation gain, 8848 m
- Only natural scenery: no roads or stairs
- No bicycles, chairlifts, buses, etc; no abseiling
- Must travel the same route back and forth repeatedly
- No sleeping
- Resting, eating and drinking are allowed; no restrictions on resupplying along the way
- The spirit of the challenge implies that your route should be mostly altitude gain, followed by descent on the way back - not a "10 m up, 10 m down" type of trail

So I wonder, first of all, which elevation gain is best for one leg of the challenge (assuming I can find any route I want, within reason)? I imagine that 3 times 3000 m would be inconvenient because of temperature differences, and 89 times 100 m would be a burden for the brain. What other factors should I take into account?

Also, which altitude profile should I use? Make it too shallow and you should travel a big distance; make it too steep and it becomes hard to go down. Should the angle be uniform, or is it better to have flatter sections along the steep ascent?

Comment: *Must travel the same route back and forth repeatedly* What fun/use is that? If I want to travel 88 kilometers with gradients of 10% that would not count? I can understand *May* instead of *Must*...

Comment: I guess one reason is to be able to verify the altitude gain from redundant GPS recordings of the same section; also it's fun to see altitude profiles like [here](http://www.everestinguk.com/2014/09/if-at-first-you-dont-succeed-have.html)

Comment: Pretty brutal.  Even if was strong enough to do it my knees would be shot.  I would pick a short peak for a quick view from the top.

Comment: Since you can only do a single mountain route, I'd rather go for one that had at least 900m of gain so I it would take <= 10 circuits. I'd get too bored doing the same route more than that. 3000m would be better to me but much harder to find. Weather would be my concern at elevation rather than just temp.

Comment: @topshot Or one could try Mt Everest to haveonly 1 circuit ;)